# What's the relationship between SOCKS and socket?

Tags: socket, socks

SOCKS (socket secure) is a protocol for proxy. A socket is an endpoint of communication.

Why is SOCKS named after socket? How are they related?

Comment: You did ask [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062247/whats-the-relationship-between-socks-and-socket) a few days ago on stackoverflow. If the answer there is not sufficient for you then please detail what you don't understand instead of asking exactly the same question again somewhere else. And note that SOCKS and socket are not specifically related to UNIX.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich good point about this not been particularly *nix related, but neither is it programming related. Almost feels like it actually belongs in superuser... maybe there's another copy of this Q there ;)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Thanks. I was not sure if you reply was correct, so I asked here for others' opinions. Sorry.

Comment: @DanSut: Can you find another copy? ;)

Comment: @Tim I was jesting but it does not appear you have asked there... yet. Maybe my answer will be good enough ;) I do find it interesting your SO and U&L SE accounts aren't connected though :/ You've obviously been on SE for eons though so I'm sure know all the tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original FAQ tells us [SOCK-et-S was its initial internal development name](https://web.archive.org/web/20070124232014/http://socks.permeo.com/TechnicalResources/SOCKSFAQ/SOCKSGeneralFAQ/index.asp#q12).

I would guess this was chosen for the simple reason that it is a proxy for socket based protocols. Only TCP up to SOCKSv4 and then with SOCKSv5 UDP as well.